# Match only if the string does not contain a certain word/s

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression to match cases where the sentence contain the words 'business intelligence'.
However, I do not want a match to be returned if the sentence contains the words 'business intelligence and analytics'.

I tried using

```
      /Business Intelligence (?<! and Analytics)/
```

Comment: I was confused too when I first read about lookaheads and lookbehinds in the sense that the names seem backward for what each does.

Comment: Which tool are you using for your regex?

Comment: The [Regex-Fu FAQ Mega Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) say: [match a string not containing a word](http://stackoverflow.com/q/406230)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use negative lookahead:

```
/Business Intelligence(?! and Analytics)/
                        ^ I have removed the < from here
```